# New 52 Justice League #1: Are all the super humans considered evil?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, justice-league

Just read the first new Justice League and from what it looked liked, everyone thought all the Super Humans were evil. Even Batman.

Is this the assumption going into the new reboot?

Comment: A comment on the downvote/close vote would be nice...

Comment: Just that you're asking for information on a comic that hasn't come out yet; all people can do is speculate.

Comment: This comic is out... Its directly asking what the base assumption is going into the new story arch...

Comment: Considered evil by whom?

Comment: This seems very on-topic to me. If anything it's a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All I have gathered from the [DC Comics blogs](http://dcu.blog.dccomics.com/category/news/), that this is a pivotal point in the initial plot, superheroes must work with UN or they are considered outlaw vigilantes. And, Batman seems to prefer the fearful attitude of the people towards the superheroes in issue#1. Furthermore, this issue takes place 5 years in the past. I heard more will be revealed in the issue#1 of ["Justice League International"](http://dcu.blog.dccomics.com/new-52-justice-league-international/).